# Cocos2d: Memory from Tilemaps is not released when parent scene closes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I’ve been running Xcode’s Instruments’ Allocations tool against my app and have found that scenes (CCNodes) with Tilemaps don’t release all their memory when deallocated. Is there something I'm missing?

The project uses ARC.

To illustrate this I’ve created a mini project with 3 class files that will reproduce the error. The class files are as follows:

RedTest
YellowTest
GreenTest

All three files are similar in that they all display a background sprite of the same size in their respective colour. All three files have two menu buttons that allow the active scene to be replaced by one of the two non-active scenes. For example: RedTest has a yellow and a green button. When one of the buttons is pressed a

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
```

instruction is called to close the active scene and open the specified new scene. So, for example, pressing the yellow button from RedTest would close RedTest and open YellowTest.

OK.  When I run this in Instruments’ Allocations I’m solely looking at the value under the [All Heap & Anonymous VM .. Live Bytes] value.

RedTest.m is called first (from app delegate) and the bytes count settles around 2.50mb. I can switch between all 3 scenes and this value remains pretty constant. At this point the code has proved we can switch between all scenes without increasing the memory footprint.

**Now it’s time to create the problem:**

In GreenTest.m I have two lines commented out that create a tile map instead of a sprite for the background. **When you comment out the sprite lines and uncomment the tile map lines I see the following behaviour:**

On starting, RedTest.m shows 2.50mb (as before). When I press the green button and the tile map is displayed the val jumps to around 2.89mb. When I press the red or yellow button the memory drops down but stays at 2.69mb. From this point on memory will always show 2.69mb (when yellow or red showing) or 2.89mb when green showing.

**So the issue is** ... that after opening and closing green theme (the one with the tile map) the base memory value has climbed from 2.50mb to 2.69mb even though everything from GreenTest.m should have been deallocated.

The three class files are listed below:

```
//  RedTest.m
#import "RedTest.h"
    @implementation RedTest
    -(id) init
    {
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        // ask director for the window size
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        //Add a background sprite.
        CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"RedBack.png"];
        background.position = ccp(size.width * 0.5f,size.height * 0.5f);
        [self addChild:background z:0];


        //Add a simple two button menu
        CCMenuItem *yellowButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                      itemWithNormalImage:@"YellowButton.png"
                                      selectedImage:@"WhiteButton.png"
                                      disabledImage:nil
                                      target:self
                                      selector:@selector(changeToYellow)];

        CCMenuItem *greenButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                    itemWithNormalImage:@"GreenButton.png"
                                    selectedImage:@"WhiteButton.png"
                                    disabledImage:nil
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(changeToGreen)];


        CCMenu * coloursMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:yellowButton,greenButton,nil];
        coloursMenu.position = CGPointZero;
        yellowButton.position = ccp(size.width * 0.30f,size.height * 0.5f);
        greenButton.position = ccp(size.width * 0.70f,size.height * 0.5f);
        [self addChild:coloursMenu z:10];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) changeToYellow {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[YellowTest node]];
}
-(void) changeToGreen {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GreenTest node]];
}
@end




//  YellowTest.m
#import "YellowTest.h"
@implementation YellowTest

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        // ask director for the window size
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        //Add a background sprite.
        CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"YellowBack.png"];
        background.position = ccp(size.width * 0.5f,size.height * 0.5f);
        [self addChild:background z:0];


        //Add a simple two button menu
        CCMenuItem *redButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                    itemWithNormalImage:@"RedButton.png"
                                    selectedImage:@"WhiteButton.png"
                                    disabledImage:nil
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(changeToRed)];

        CCMenuItem *greenButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                   itemWithNormalImage:@"GreenButton.png"
                                   selectedImage:@"WhiteButton.png"
                                   disabledImage:nil
                                   target:self
                                   selector:@selector(changeToGreen)];


        CCMenu * coloursMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:redButton,greenButton,nil];
        coloursMenu.position = CGPointZero;
        redButton.position = ccp(size.width * 0.30f,size.height * 0.5f);
        greenButton.position = ccp(size.width * 0.70f,size.height * 0.5f);
        [self addChild:coloursMenu z:10];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) changeToRed {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[RedTest node]];
}

-(void) changeToGreen {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GreenTest node]];
}

@end




@implementation GreenTest
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        // ask director for the window size
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        //Add a background sprite.


        //*******  These two lines for the sprite
        //CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"GreenBack.png"];
        //background.position = ccp(size.width * 0.5f,size.height * 0.5f);


        //*******  These two lines for the tilemap.
        CCTMXTiledMap *background = [CCTMXTiledMap   tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"GreenTileMap.tmx"];
    background.position = ccp(0,0);

        [self addChild:background z:0];


        //Add a simple two button menu
        CCMenuItem *yellowButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                    itemWithNormalImage:@"YellowButton.png"
                                    selectedImage:@"WhiteButton.png"
                                    disabledImage:nil
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(changeToYellow)];

        CCMenuItem *redButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                   itemWithNormalImage:@"RedButton.png"
                                   selectedImage:@"WhiteButton.png"
                                   disabledImage:nil
                                   target:self
                                   selector:@selector(changeToRed)];


        CCMenu * coloursMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:yellowButton,redButton,nil];
        coloursMenu.position = CGPointZero;
        yellowButton.position = ccp(size.width * 0.30f,size.height * 0.5f);
        redButton.position = ccp(size.width * 0.70f,size.height * 0.5f);
        [self addChild:coloursMenu z:10];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) changeToYellow {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[YellowTest node]];
}

-(void) changeToRed {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[RedTest node]];
}
@end
```

Comment: Two things to do: 1) check whether a (or one of) the tilemap objects is still listed under the "living" objects list in Instruments. 2) Run an analyze build, perhaps this may point out a memory management issue, ie retain cycle are rather common in cocos2d (strong reference to sibling or parent node can suffice).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've looked at living objects and can only see a few hundred bytes that obviously relate to CCTXTilemaps and I need to be accounting for nearly 100k.   Analyze build didn't highlight any of my code but brought up a few lines from the Cocos2d libraries. I'm feeling this example code is so paired down that the problem is more likely to be with the Cocos2d libraries and I'm surprised that the many other coders that use tile maps haven't seen this error.

Comment: Override the `onExit` method.Inside that call the `[self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES]` and also called `[super exit]`.

Comment: Nimisha. Thank you for your suggestion. I added the code as you suggested to Greentest.m but it hasn't made any difference.